# Symfony forms override field appearance

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-forms

I'm trying to override field appearance.

I created my custom form type:

```
namespace AppBundle\Form\Type\Frontend\Search;

/**/

class TripTypeType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'choices'     => [
                'One-way',
                'Round-trip',
            ],
            'multiple'    => false,
            'expanded'    => true,
            'required'    => false,
            'empty_value' => false,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getParent()
    {
        return ChoiceType::class;
    }
}
```

After that i added this field to parent form:

```
namespace AppBundle\Form\Type\Frontend\Search;

/***/

class FlightSearchType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('tripType', TripTypeType::class)
            ->add('airports', AirportsType::class)
            ->add('flightAt', FlightDatesType::class)
            ->add('flightClass', FlightClassType::class);
    }
}
```

And rendering this field like that:

```
{% for type in form.tripType %}
    {% if loop.index == 1 %}
        {% set way_id = 'one-way' %}
    {% else %}
        {% set way_id = 'round-trip' %}
    {% endif %}

    {{ form_widget(type, {
        'id': way_id,
        'attr': {'class': 'tabs-way__radio'},
        'label_attr': {'class': 'tabs-way__label', 'for': way_id}
    }) }}
{% endfor %}
```

So what i want to get is a:

```
<div class="tabs-way__item">
    <input type="radio" id="one-way" name="flight_search[tripType]" class="tabs-way__radio" value="0">
    <label class="tabs-way__label" for="one-way">One-way</label>
</div>
```

For that i'm trying to override widget for this field:

```
{# app/Resources/views/Form/fields.html.twig #}
{% block trip_type_widget %}
    <div class="tabs-way__item">
        <input type="radio" {{ block('widget_attributes') }}{% if value is defined %} value="{{ value }}"{% endif %}{% if checked %} checked="checked"{% endif %} />
        {{ block('form_label') }}
    </div>
{% endblock trip_type_widget %}
```

And i include that file in `config.yml` in twig section. But all i get it's nothing :(

Answer (score 0):

If you need to override custom field, you have to [prefix it with underscore](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#how-to-customize-an-individual-field), e.g.:

```
{% block _trip_type_widget %}
    <div class="tabs-way__item">
        {{- form_label(form) -}}
        {{- form_widget(form) -}}
        {{- form_errors(form) -}}
    </div>
{% endblock _trip_type_widget %}
```

Comment: Actually it didn't helped. I don't know why, block by names `_trip_type_widget`, `_trip_widget`, `tripType_widget`, `trip_type_widget` just not working.

Comment: Use Symfony Profiler (Form debugger) to see [unique block prefix](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OAyAW.png) of your form widget.